# Reading a file and then sorting it into 10 columns

Tags: c

I'm looking to sort a txt file that contains 1199 numbers in 10 columns per row, and I know that the last row will have 10 or fewer columns.
However, I'm getting 11 columns on the first row.

Thanks for the help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define t 1024

int main()
{
    int i=0, c;
    char p[t];
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("CMB.txt", "r");
    while ((c = getc(f)) != EOF)
    {
        fscanf(f, "%s", p);
        if(i%10 == 0 && i > 0)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("%s ", p);
        if (c == '\n')
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n %d", i+1);
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: Print `c` inside the loop, before the `fscanf()`

Comment: do you mean to put printf("%s ", p) before scanf ? if so it didn't help ;/

Comment: I meant `printf("c is %d (%c)\n", c, c);`

Comment: ok, now it prints the numbers 10 at a time but not in columns

Comment: When I try your code it prints correctly the 10 columns you are expecting , perhaps you didn't recompile after modifying.#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    //, c;
   // char p[t];
   // FILE *f;
   // f = fopen("CMB.txt", "r");
    while (i<30)
    {
      //  fscanf(f, "%s", p);
        if(i%10 == 0 && i > 0)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("%d ", i);
       // if (c == '\n')
       // {
            i++;
       // }
    }
    // printf("\n %d", i+1);
   // fclose(f);
}

Comment: Read a line at a time with `fgets`, and parse with `sscanf` (with 10 conversion specifiers) making use of the return of `sscanf` to determine the number of fields filled.

Answer (score 0):

When I try your code it prints correctly the 10 columns you are expecting , perhaps you didn't recompile after modifying.
This is your code , I only removed the file reading and printing char.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
    {
        int i=0;
        //, c;
       // char p[t];
       // FILE *f;
       // f = fopen("CMB.txt", "r");
        while (i<30)
        {
          //  fscanf(f, "%s", p);
            if(i%10 == 0 && i > 0)
            {
                printf("\n");
            }
            printf("%d ", i);
           // if (c == '\n')
           // {
                i++;
           // }
        }
        // printf("\n %d", i+1);
       // fclose(f);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but i dont get what im supposed to change? do i change the while loop or what? thanks for the help btw

Comment: I didn't change anything to your code, except commenting out the file related stuff. I compiled and it displays 10 columns. Is there a chance you call the wrong executable ? Try delete your object files , executable file, rebuild and run again.

Comment: No the i did it for me aswell but for some reson the fscanf onley reads 1198 insted of 1199

Comment: Hi BURITOS, I was commenting on your question : "However, I'm getting 11 columns on the first row." , the code above prints 0 to 9 and that is 10 columns on first column.

Comment: Could you send me the exakt one you build ?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you read a character before the first number? Why do you only increment `i` if this character is a newline?

If the file contains just numbers, you can simplify the code this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, n;
    FILE *f = fopen("CMB.txt", "r");
    if (f != NULL) {
        for (i = 0; fscanf(f, "%d", &n) == 1; i++) {
            /* output the number followed by a tab, or by a newline every 10 numbers */
            printf("%d%c", n, "\t\n"[i % 10 == 9]);
        }
        if (i % 10 != 0) {
            printf("\n");
        }
        fclose(f);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @buritos: `n` is an `int`, `fscanf()` stores the numbers read from the file into it. I updated the code with a proper  definition for it.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my earlier comment, when reading columns of data from a text file, it is generally better to read a line of input at a time with a *line-oriented* input function such as `fgets` or POSIX `getline` and then to parse the data from the buffer filled with `sscanf` (or walking a pointer down the buffer picking out what you need)

In your case when dealing with a fixed number of columns (10) where less than all values may be present, `sscanf` provides a way to determine exactly how many values are present in each row while allowing you to make use of the data if less than 10 are present.

`sscanf` (as with all `scanf` functions) returns the number of successful conversions took place based on the *format string* you provide (or returning `EOF` if the end of input is encountered before a conversion takes place). If you want to read 10-integer values from each line of data into an integer array names `arr`, you could use `fgets` to read the line into a buffer (say `buf`) and then separate the integer values head in buf with `sscanf`, e.g.

```
    ...
    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) { /* read each line into buf */
        /* parse into integer values with sscanf saving return */
        int rtn = sscanf (buf, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d",
                        &arr[0], &arr[1], &arr[2], &arr[3], &arr[4],
                        &arr[5], &arr[6], &arr[7], &arr[8], &arr[9]);
    ...
```

Then you simply validate the return (`rtn`) using whatever `if..else` or `switch...` statements you need. Here we can simply sum the number of values read and output the row number for any row containing less than `COL` number of values for purposes of this example, e.g.

```
        ...
        if (rtn > 0)    /* did at least one conversion take place? */
            n += rtn;   /* increment count of values read */

        if (rtn < COL)  /* were less than COL values read? */
            printf ("row[%zu]: %d values read.\n", row + 1, rtn);

        row++;  /* increment row count */
    }
```

Putting it altogether, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define COL    10
#define MAXC 1024

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC];
    int arr[COL] = {0};
    size_t n = 0, row = 0;
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) { /* read each line into buf */
        /* parse into integer values with sscanf saving return */
        int rtn = sscanf (buf, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d",
                        &arr[0], &arr[1], &arr[2], &arr[3], &arr[4],
                        &arr[5], &arr[6], &arr[7], &arr[8], &arr[9]);
        if (rtn > 0)    /* did at least one conversion take place? */
            n += rtn;   /* increment count of values read */

        if (rtn < COL)  /* were less than COL values read? */
            printf ("row[%zu]: %d values read.\n", row + 1, rtn);

        row++;  /* increment row count */
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    printf ("%zu values read from file.\n", n);
}
```

**Example Input File**

Reading a data file with 10-integers per-row for 119 rows and reading a final row with 9-integers as you describe in your question, you could use an input file like:

```
$ head -n4 dat/1199_10col.txt; echo "<snip>"; tail -n4 dat/1199_10col.txt
    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20
   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30
   31   32   33   34   35   36   37   38   39   40
<snip>
 1161 1162 1163 1164 1165 1166 1167 1168 1169 1170
 1171 1172 1173 1174 1175 1176 1177 1178 1179 1180
 1181 1182 1183 1184 1185 1186 1187 1188 1189 1190
 1191 1192 1193 1194 1195 1196 1197 1198 1199
```

**Example Use/Output**

Running the code against the above file would yield the expected results of reading 1199 values, 10-integers per-row with 9-integers read from the final row with notice of the short row:

```
$ ./bin/read10col <dat/1199_10col.txt
row[120]: 9 values read.
1199 values read from file.
```

While there are many ways to do this, and arguably using `fgets` with `strtol` provides opportunity for finer grained error detection, this is probably one of the more simple and straight-forward approaches.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: thanks for the help but dont really understand everything, possible to make it a shorter code?

Comment: That's about as short as it gets. Think of it this was. `fgets` read the entire line into `buf`. Then `sscanf` separates the integers in `buf` into `arr[0], arr[1], ...` and returns the number of integers it found (up to the 10 conversion specifiers within the format string, e.g. `"%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d"` (10 conversions to `int`). You would then use those values however you needed. E.g. to store in a larger 2D array, a struct, or do calculations based on them. What part are you stuck on?

Comment: You can always shorten the top of the code by simply hardcoding your filename (which is the wrong thing to do). That would remove the ability to pass the filename as the first argument to the program or read from `stdin` if no argument is provided (as should be done). In C, it is up to you to validate every critical step in your program. If you call `fopen`, you must validate it succeeded. If you read a line of data, you must validate it succeeded. If you attempt to parse 10-integers from that line, you must validate it succeeded, and so on ...

Comment: Thanks for the tips :D

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  FILE * fp;
  char *line;
  int i;
  size_t len = 0;
  fp = fopen("CMB.txt", "r");

  while (getline(&line, &len, fp) != -1)
  {
    fscanf(fp, "%s", line);
    if(i%10 == 0 && i > 0)
    {
      printf("\n");
    }
    printf("%s\t ", line);
    i++;
  }
  printf("\n\n%d", i);
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

So now the numbers from the file are sorted in 10 columns, but the last line only have 8 columns when it should have 9. When I count (i) to see how many lines the while loop reads it only reads 1198, but i should read 1199. So I'm guessing it's skipping the first line? Appreciate the help :D

Comment: `i` is uninitialized, its initial value is probably `0` but not guaranteed. The first line has 11 numbers, not 10.`i` should be initialized to `0` and the test should be `if (i%10 == 9)`

Comment: well the first line does not have 11 numbers it has 10 when i run the program. And when i tried i=0 and (i%10 == 9) it gives me 9 numbers so ?

Comment: My mistake, you do test for newline printing **before** printing the number read from the file. Testing `if (i % 10 == 9)` after you print the number would avoid the need for the extra `i > 0` test. What does the program print at the end of the listing? 1198 or 1199?